# parser-tools: case insensitive lexer?

Tags: racket

I'm writing a parser using parser-tools.  The language is case-insensitive.  Is there a way to make case-insensitive lexers with this library?

What I tried:

```
#lang racket

(require parser-tools/lex
         (prefix-in : parser-tools/lex-sre)
         parser-tools/yacc)

(define-empty-tokens words
  (YES EOF))

;; Does not work with "yes", but works with "YES".
(define my-lexer
  (lexer
   [(eof) (token-EOF)]
   ["YES" (token-YES)]))

;; Works, but won't scale up to dozens of tokens
(define my-case-insensitive-lexer
  (lexer
   [(eof) (token-EOF)]
   [(:or "YES" "yes" "Yes" "YEs" "YeS" "yeS" "yEs" "yeS" "yES") (token-YES)]))

(define (lex lexer s)
  (with-input-from-string s (thunk (lexer (current-input-port)))))

(lex my-lexer "Yes") ; -> No match found in input starting with: Ye
(lex my-case-insensitive-lexer "Yes") ; -> 'YES
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the documentation, I don't see a way. You can always force the input to be one case though:

```lisp
(define (lex lexer s)
  (call-with-input-string (string-upcase s) lexer))
```

---

Or maybe write a lexer macro that processes strings to turn them into case-insensitive patterns:

```lisp
#lang racket/base

(require (for-syntax racket/base) racket/port parser-tools/lex)

(define-empty-tokens words
  (YES EOF))

(define-lex-trans case-insensitive
  (lambda (stx)
    #`(concatenation #,@(for/list ([c (in-string (cadr (syntax->datum stx)))])
                          (list 'union (char-upcase c) (char-downcase c))))))

(define my-lexer
  (lexer
   [(eof) (token-EOF)]
   [(case-insensitive "YES") (token-YES)]))

(define (lex lexer s) (call-with-input-string s lexer))
(writeln (lex my-lexer "Yes")) ; YES
```

Comment: `define-lex-trans` worked well, thanks!